# SqlAlchemy. TypeError: filter_by() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, upgrade

I upgraded sqlalchemy from 0.7 to 0.9.6. After upgrade I am getting the following error:

```
TypeError
TypeError: filter_by() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)
```

howerver before it was working without any issue. How can I manage that issue?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Without seeing code, obviously you are calling [`filter_by`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/orm/query.html#sqlalchemy.orm.query.Query.filter_by) wrong. `filter_by` takes only the implicit `self` (the *'exactly 1 argument'* meaning exactly 1 positional argument) and optional keyword arguments. You are providing `filter_by` another positional argument, possibly a dictionary.

The syntax is:

```
query.filter_by(column1=value, column2=value)
```

Whereas for `filter`:

```
query.filter(Model.column1 == value, Model.column2 == value)
```

Comment: `filter_by` should never have been added. it's confusing and contradicts expected behaviour e.g. compared to `order_by`

Comment: Which is why I (almost) never use `filter_by`